# Why does calling the SD.begin() function multiple times in the Arduino IDE trigger a software WDT?

Tags: esp8266, sd-card

I want to get an AZ-Delivery SPI Reader Micro SD Card Module working on a NodeMCU Lua Lolin V3 ESP8266MOD 12-F. The module is correctly connected to the SPI pins of the NodeMCU: CLK (D5), MOSI (D7), MISO (D6) and I have chosen D8 as the CS pin.

To use the board, the URL "**https://arduino.esp8266.com/stable/package_esp8266com_index.json**" was added to the additional Boards Manager, and the board library "esp8266 by ESP8266 Community" is installed.

This code works perfectly fine, whether the SD card is inserted or not:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  
  if (SD.begin(D8)) {
    Serial.println("SD card detected");
  } else {
    Serial.println("SD card not detected");
  }
}

void loop() {}
```

However, if the function `SD.begin(D8)` is called twice (e.g. when it is called in the `loop()`) and the SD card is NOT inserted, a software WDT interrupts the program.

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() { 
  if (SD.begin(D8)) {
    Serial.println("SD card detected");
  } else {
    Serial.println("SD card not detected");
  }
}
```

**Serial Monitor:**

> SD card not detected
>
> --------------- CUT HERE FOR EXCEPTION DECODER ---------------
>
> Soft WDT reset
>
> >>>stack>>>
>
> ctx: cont
> sp: 3ffffd10 end: 3fffffd0 offset: 01a0
> 3ffffeb0:  00000000 00001942 63958106 001d34c3
> 3ffffec0:  00000000 00000001 00000000 00000003
> 3ffffed0:  000000ff 3ffef8e8 00001957 40204bd7
> 3ffffee0:  003d0900 00000000 3ffef8e8 40204d4d
> 3ffffef0:  00000000 00000000 0000000f 401002c8
> 3fffff00:  003d0900 00000000 3ffef8e8 40205036
> 3fffff10:  40106085 00134c1e 3ffee950 00000000
> 3fffff20:  4020000f 003d0900 00000000 3ffee950
> 3fffff30:  00000000 00000fef f6c8b439 3ffee978
> 3fffff40:  3ffef8e8 3ffef68c 3ffef8e8 40205165
> 3fffff50:  4020000f 000003e8 00000c07 402060ad
> 3fffff60:  00000000 00000c07 00000000 40202031
> 3fffff70:  4020000f 3ffe88a9 3ffee8f8 3ffee978
> 3fffff80:  3ffef68c 3ffef684 3ffef884 402020a4
> 3fffff90:  3fffdad0 3ffee8c0 3ffee8f8 402010aa
> 3fffffa0:  53444653 00000f00 003d0900 feefeffe
> 3fffffb0:  feefeffe 00000000 3ffee94c 40206154
> 3fffffc0:  feefeffe feefeffe 3fffdab0 40101039
> <<<stack<<<
>
> --------------- CUT HERE FOR EXCEPTION DECODER ---------------
>
> ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,6)
>
> load 0x4010f000, len 3424, room 16
> tail 0
> chksum 0x2e
> load 0x3fff20b8, len 40, room 8
> tail 0
> chksum 0x2b
> csum 0x2b
> v0004a440
> ~ld

[ESP Exception Decoder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Stfgv.png)

**Why does the WDT interrupt the program?**

I tried to follow the implementation of the `SD.begin()` function, but quickly got overwhelmed by the many files, classes, and functions involved. Are there any tricks/techniques to understand such a complex API or is it a matter of just powering through it?

I am grateful for any help

Comment: The dog need to be feed, if you holding-up all the resources by constantly looping, the dog will choked. You need to feed the dog. The easiest way to feed the dog is add a `yield()` or `delay(1)` into your `loop`. Read "Yielding" section of [ESP8266 Thing Hookup Guide](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/esp8266-thing-hookup-guide/using-the-arduino-addon) for more detail.

Comment: I understand what you mean and I think that is exactly the problem. However, adding a `delay()` or `yield()` in the main loop won't help. The watchdog timer still interrupts the program. I suspect the corresponding loop is somewhere in the SD library, but I can't find it. (Unfortunately, I can't make sense of the exception decoder either -.-)

Comment: you can install the [ESP Exception Decoder](https://github.com/me-no-dev/EspExceptionDecoder) plugin to Arduino IDE to decode the exception message.